# make apexcharts responsive and higher

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

I have a apex chart like this:

[image]

On computer all is fine.
But now I would make it responsive and I tried this code:

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'bar'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: false,
                    columnWidth: '80%'
                },
            },          
            series: [{
                name: 'Umsatz',
                data: umsatzSumMonat
            }, {
                name: 'Ausgaben',
                data: ausgabenSumMonat
            }],
            xaxis: {
                  categories: ['Jan','Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            },
            responsive: [{
                  breakpoint: 1000,
                  yaxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan','Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez']
                  },
                  options: {
                    plotOptions: {
                      bar: {
                        horizontal: true
                      }
                    }
                  }
            }]
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts( document.querySelector("#myChart"), options );
        chart.render();
```

Result:

[image]

But the bars are to small (not high enough).
How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to also increase height of your chart in responsive options:

```
chart: {
    height: 450
},
```

Bars should then stretch a bit...